# JavaCv and FFMpeg

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv, android-ffmpeg

I was given a task to merge an Image and Audio to make a video file out of them in android. I successfully finished the task by using javacv ffmpeg but after so much of compression my app size is still around 15mb. After analysing the apk, I've found that libavcodec.so is occupying 64% of the size. Since my app relies on that, I can't exclude the file.
So my question is "Is it feasible to complete this task with very less apk size? Like around < 5Mb?"

Comment: Could you clarify as to why the rest of your APK is so large? Android apps are typically not that big if you're careful. What frameworks are you using?

Comment: Did you compile with debug information?

Comment: You can build different variants of Android application for different platform like armabi, x86  etc.. It will reduce apk size.

Comment: @KG6ZVP The rest of the size is also occupied by .So files only!  I'm using bytedeco ffmpeg library which invloves javacv in it!.

Comment: @Parth I've already used Split ABI to split my apk's and that's the reason why it is 15 mb now, before it was around 60mb.

Comment: @chtz yeah I've compiled with debug info

Comment: ohk.. You can have a look at https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/247. It may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. If you really want to use javacv than you can remove unnecessary parts from the sources and recompile them. [More info in JavaCPP repo](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp/wiki/Build-Script)

As the easiest solluton of this problem you can just remove some unused .so files.

Finally, ffmpeg is not necessary here and you can find another solution. For example you can use an online service (I've found transloadit and it is free for small apps) or write your own native or java code. It is not easy but possible